# Remember last selected option from dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want that our website should remember the last selected option from drop down when he visit again. I'm trying it with jQuery cookies but it's not working.

Here is my select dropdown code

```
<form action="results.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
                <input id="search" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search.." autocomplete="off">
                <select name="city" id="city">
                    <?php 
                        $sql="SELECT * FROM tcity";
                        $connect= mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ("Failed To Connect.");
                        while($rows= mysqli_fetch_array($connect, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ ?>
                            <option value= "<?php echo $rows['c_id']?>" id="optin_val"><?php echo $rows['city_nm'];?></option>
                        <?php }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </form>
```

Beacuse i'm using it as filter with my search bar i read the value on keyup function my jquery i tried is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#search').keyup(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        var val = $('#city').val();
        Cookies.set('dropdown',val);
        if ( value != ""){
            $('#my-search').show();
            var dropCookie = Cookies.get('dropdown');
            $.post('functions/search_bar.php', {value: value, val: dropCookie}, function(data){
                $('#my-search').html(data);
            });
        }else{
            $('#my-search').hide();
        }
    });
```

As you can see I tried to use cookie to remember the selection but its not working as it takes the first option again when the page is refreshed.

Comment: you have to cookie expiry time

Comment: What if i dont want to expire that cookie.. and let the user selection to be remembered irrespective of time..?

Comment: Bit hard to follow you, shouldn't you be checking for ```$_POST['val']``` and echoing ```selected``` in the option output?

Comment: where  have you used $('#my-search') this id?

Comment: yeah i'm using $_POST['val'] in search function to filter by city

Comment: $('#my-search') is just a output place where search results will be shown...@prakashtank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) or similar?

This is not tested, but if the cookie is set then you could do the following:

```
<form action="results.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
    <input id="search" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search.." autocomplete="off">
    <select name="city" id="city">
        <?php 
            $sql="SELECT * FROM tcity";
            $connect= mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ("Failed To Connect.");
            while($rows= mysqli_fetch_array($connect, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ ?>
                <option value= "<?php echo $rows['c_id']?>" id="optin_val" <?php echo (!empty($_COOKIE['dropdown']) && $_COOKIE['dropdown'] == $rows['c_id'] ? 'selected' : ''); ?>><?php echo $rows['city_nm'];?></option>
            <?php }
        ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

Notice where php checks `$_COOKIE['dropdown']` and outputs `selected` if it equals the option value on this line:

```
<option value= "<?php echo $rows['c_id']?>" id="optin_val" <?php echo (!empty($_COOKIE['dropdown']) && $_COOKIE['dropdown'] == $rows['c_id'] ? 'selected' : ''); ?>><?php echo $rows['city_nm'];?></option>
```

Comment: But i'm bit confused with its working..can u please explain in one or two lines

Comment: I have edited the answer. All I did was add this in your while loop ```<?php echo (!empty($_COOKIE['dropdown']) && $_COOKIE['dropdown'] == $rows['c_id'] ? 'selected' : ''); ?>```

Comment: i understood that part..but i din't get  ---  ? 'selected' : '');  ---

Comment: Thanks a lot.. after working on php for so long i dint have idea of that..

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Jquery.Cookie` for this case.

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Then save dropdown value in cookie like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var selectedVal = jQuery.cookie("selected-val");
  if (selectedVal) {
    jQuery("#city").val(selectedVal);
  }
  jQuery("#city").on("change", function(){
    var selection = jQuery(this).val();
    jQuery.cookie("selected-val", selection, {expires: 365, path: '/'})
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this answer you might get some help..

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#search').keyup(function(){
            var value = $(this).val();
            var val = $('#city').val();
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
            document.cookie = "dropdown=" + val + expires + "; path=/";
         //   Cookies.set('dropdown',val);
            if ( value != ""){
                $('#my-search').show();
                var dropCookie = getCookie("dropdown");
                $.post('functions/search_bar.php', {value: value, val: dropCookie}, function(data){
                    $('#my-search').html(data);
                });
           }else{
               $('#my-search').hide();
           }
  });
function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];

            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                return (c.substring(name.length, c.length));
            }
        }
    }
```